# perl - Argument "xxx" isn't numeric in printf

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read the first 4 bytes (which is supposed to be an uint32_t indicating the file header size) out of a binary file with the following code:

```
 sysopen(my $inHandle, $fileName, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY) 
     or croak("Failed to open file $fileName");
 die if(read($inHandle, my $currDword, 4) != 4);
 printf("length is %d\n", $currDword);
```

And it's giving me

```
Argument "M-\f^B" isn't numeric in printf at sbin.pl line 12.
length is 0
```

Did I mess up something? Also does perl handle endianness automatically (binary is little endian), or is there some other way to grab the bytes? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `unpack()` to convert a binary number into a perl number.

Answer (score 9):

You need to convert the four bytes into a number. Assuming it's an unsigned integer, two of the following will do depending on the order of the bytes:

```
my $hsize = unpack('N',  $currDword);  # Big-endian    12 34 56 78 => 0x12345678
my $hsize = unpack('L>', $currDword);  # Big-endian    12 34 56 78 => 0x12345678
my $hsize = unpack('V',  $currDword);  # Little-endian 12 34 56 78 => 0x78563412
my $hsize = unpack('L<', $currDword);  # Little-endian 12 34 56 78 => 0x78563412
```